# how to draw offline circle of 1500 meters range over the geocoordinate in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I want draw the offline circle over the geocoordinate in windows phone 
this circle is of 1500 meter range and it search the target within this range

[image]
this my image where i have point to draw circle using width and heigth but i want to draw circle
using radius while i zoom, the range of the circle also affected

and also search the target within this range or not

```
    //  double metersPerPixels = (Math.Cos(geo.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.Pow(2, map.ZoomLevel));
    // double radius = 1000 / metersPerPixels;



    map.Layers.Add(new MapLayer()
          {
            new MapOverlay()
            {
                GeoCoordinate = geo,                   
                PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5),   
                 Content = new Ellipse
                {   

                    Opacity=.4,
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color),
                    Width = 100,//radius * 2 
                    Height =100 //adius * 2 

                }
             }                
          });
```

Comment: Not tested or done this myself yet, but there is a very interesting ( but old ) blog post about adding circles ( and shapes ) in regards to x amount of meters here http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.be/2011/10/drawing-shapes-on-top-of-bing-maps-in.html#!/2011/10/drawing-shapes-on-top-of-bing-maps-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, you can use it with your own class by changing the `Location` class in this helper.

Here is the sample helper to create a circle out of the initializing point and radius in meter:

```
/// <summary>
/// The geo drawing helper.
/// </summary>
public class GeoDrawingHelper
{
    #region Constants

    /// <summary>
    /// The c_ earth radius in kilometers.
    /// </summary>
    public const double c_EarthRadiusInKilometers = 6367.0;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a circle by the initializing point.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="center">
    /// The center Point.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="radius">
    /// The radius in meter.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="List"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static List<Location> CreateCirclePoints(Location center, double radius)
    {
        double lat = ToRadian(center.Latitude); // radians
        double lng = ToRadian(center.Longitude); // radians
        double d = radius / (c_EarthRadiusInKilometers * 1000); // d = angular distance covered on earth's surface
        var locations = new List<Location>();

        for (var x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
        {
            // Calculate the coordinates of the point
            double brng = ToRadian(x);
            double latRadians = Math.Asin((Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Cos(d)) + (Math.Cos(lat) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(brng)));
            double lngRadians = lng
                                + Math.Atan2(
                                    Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(lat), 
                                    Math.Cos(d) - (Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(latRadians)));

            // Add the location
            locations.Add(new Location() { Latitude = ToDegrees(latRadians), Longitude = ToDegrees(lngRadians) });
        }

        return locations;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the radian to degrees measure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="radians">
    /// The radians.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="double"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static double ToDegrees(double radians)
    {
        return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the degrees to radian measure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="degrees">
    /// The degrees.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="double"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static double ToRadian(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: how can i call CreateCirclePoints()

Comment: In this specific case, you would be able to do something like: GeoDrawingHelper.CreateCirclePoints(myLocation, 1500); and it will returns a list of Location and then use it as coordinates for a MapPolygon

Comment: i have geocoordinate in instead of location and how can call this through mappolygon

Comment: Location (in this sample) is a custom class with Latitude and Longitude properties. Adapting the code so you use GeoCoordinate won't be a hard thing to do.

Comment: there is conversion error In place of list<Location> i have use GeoCoordinateCollection  and replace loaction by geocordinate

Comment: This code does not fit perfectly your final implementation and might require a small adaptation on your side (like changing the type of elements that stores your geographical information as well as the return type but the most important part is not the type of the element you need but rather the way it has been configure to generate the circle location around the original location and with the given radius

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47865/discussion-between-rehan-parvez-and-nicolas-boonaert)

Comment: hi please see the chat room

Answer (score 1):

To prevent elipses on sertain latitudes I use the following code:

```
// Function to draw circle on map:

private void DrawCircle(BasicGeoposition CenterPosition, int Radius)
    {
    Color FillColor = Colors.Purple;
    Color StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
    FillColor.A = 80;
    StrokeColor.A = 80;
    Circle = new MapPolygon
        {
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            FillColor = FillColor,
            StrokeColor = StrokeColor,
            Path = new Geopath(Functions.CalculateCircle(CenterPosition, Radius))
        };
    mpBingMaps.MapElements.Add(Circle);
}

// Constants and helper functions:

const double earthRadius = 6371000D;
const double Circumference = 2D * Math.PI * earthRadius;

public static List<BasicGeoposition> CalculateCircle(BasicGeoposition Position, double Radius)
{
    List<BasicGeoposition> GeoPositions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        double Bearing = ToRad(i);
        double CircumferenceLatitudeCorrected = 2D * Math.PI * Math.Cos(ToRad(Position.Latitude)) * earthRadius;
        double lat1 = Circumference / 360D * Position.Latitude;
        double lon1 = CircumferenceLatitudeCorrected / 360D * Position.Longitude;
        double lat2 = lat1 + Math.Sin(Bearing) * Radius;
        double lon2 = lon1 + Math.Cos(Bearing) * Radius;
        BasicGeoposition NewBasicPosition = new BasicGeoposition();
        NewBasicPosition.Latitude = lat2 / (Circumference / 360D);
        NewBasicPosition.Longitude = lon2 / (CircumferenceLatitudeCorrected / 360D);
        GeoPositions.Add(NewBasicPosition);
    }
    return GeoPositions;
}

private static double ToRad(double degrees)
{
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180D);
}
```

This code is usefull for small radius of less than a few miles.